# safely upgrade glibc on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, update, upgrade, glibc, libc6

I've tried a python application on my CentOS machine and it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /tmp/_MEI2BYIr4/libstdc++.so.6)
```

I've been tempted to upgrade GLIBC, but after having read some forums it seems I could break the system. Do you know any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: it seems already dubious to have libstdc++ in /tmp/ . Was it done by the python application?

Comment: There is no reason for any legitimate Python application to have placed a copy of a system C/C++ library under `/tmp`. Contact its developer and make sure you got a correct and clean copy of the program, and ensure that your system does not have malware now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Believe it or not, this looks like it's legit. The exact same path appears in a Github issue related to a bioinformatics tool: https://github.com/BioinformaticsFMRP/TCGAbiolinks/issues/162#issuecomment-360149428

Comment: @duskwuff OK, that's a little bizarre. What on earth do they think they're doing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Scientists, man. As long as the research gets done…

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, I'm in fact the guy stuck with that bioinformatics tool.

Answer (score 20):

#### Check it is actually needed

Firstly check the python application as it could be out of date and is probably misreading the `glibc` version. CentOS shows the base version as installed and is patched to keep up with changes and it could just be a case of fixing the version that is being looked for in the code as a quick fix, but if the application is being actively developed you need to let the developers know or fork it for yourself if you can.

An up to date `glibc` on CentOS 7 should be `2.17-196.el7_4.2`

#### If it is needed, Containerise

If it's absolutely necessary to run this application, the official RHEL approach would be to containerize, but you would still need to provide a working glibc, which wouldn't be possible with stock CentOS 7.

#### As a last resort, install `glibc` in a nonstandard location

If this isn't viable, and as an absolute last resort, it is possible to install a newer version of `glibc` than 2.18 as that is 9 years old now and `glibc` has been updated for several vulnerabilities and I'm not sure off the top of my head if it will build with the version of `make` in CentOS 7, but any newer version should work as follows:

- **This can potentially affect the functionality of your computer so make sure you know what you are doing**

You can build the version of `glibc` you require elsewhere on your server and add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the application. Note this must only be done for the application only.

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.18.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-2.18.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.18
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.18
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Then to run a binary you need to use `patchelf` to update its interpreter

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 program_you_are_running
```

And you need to enable it to find the new glibc library, either by

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/glibc-2.18/lib
```

Or you can use `patchelf` to update the binary's rpath (you can combine this with the previous `pathelf` command)

```
patchelf --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.18/lib:/usr/lib64 program_you_are_running
```

If you change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` don't export it for the whole system because all the binaries unmodified by `patchelf` will segfault.

`/opt` is the standard place to install third-party applications and libraries but you can use any path away from the system paths.

Comment: This is really bad advice. glibc is not an ordinary library; installing it under a nonstandard path is likely to make the system unbootable.

Comment: @duskwuff why, when it is only being called from an environment being set up to run this particular application?

Comment: glibc includes boot-critical components like `ld.so`, and installing it may write configuration files to global locations like `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Comment: It doesn't if you build it with `--prefix` as I specified there. It's not a good solution but it works if it's unavoidable. I updated my answer with other options and that should really be a last resort.

Comment: This is kind of the right answer, but it's also extremely dangerous. I don't think that's stressed enough here. We spent years in the late 1990s and early 2000s dealing with broken systems when people tried to upgrade glibc in place. If one isn't careful, one might accidentally replace system glibc with a different version and cause a broken system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I agree, also with your observation above (in fact the code behaviour is familiar from something I've built recently but can't remember what) and I'd try and restrict as much as I could but there are cases for doing it and it's not something to do lightly.

Comment: I've tried this option and in the end, when I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH, no command works.

Comment: @PacoelCuqui updated the answer, my mistake. However, please look at the first part of the answer as building an external glibc is the absolute last resort.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with installing libraries in a _NON-standard_ path.  The problem here is _exporting_ LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which as @PacoelCuqui found, breaks everything, because then ALL programs run by any shell with the export use the new libc.  The trick is to not export LD_LIBRARY_PATH but to place it on the command line ahead of the only the binaries which need it: `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.18/lib my_special_program`.  A complication here is that it must be used before `python prog.py` which means Python also runs with the new libc - which could be a problem.

Comment: "Containerize"- I understand that, but how would you update its glibc.  Would you do the "last resort" in the standard location?  That protects the host system but would it muck up the apps within the container?

Comment: Unfortunately I found the same as @PacoelCuqui - if I compile a more modern glibc and add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then every command just segfaults.

Comment: Ah you have to update the interpreter as in Mark's answer. I'll update this one.

Comment: How do we install patchelf since it's removed from yum and dnf package managers?

Answer (score 4):

In the end,I did not have to upgrade GLIBC. The `gdc-client` tool I downloaded through R seemed to be for Ubuntu and not CentOS, though I did it on CentOS 7. I then downloaded the gdc-client for CentOS  and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS 7, I included the `/usr/lib64` folder in the `rpath` as follows

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.18/lib:/usr/lib64 pydio-agent
```

This worked for me